# how to add my custom token to 0x protocol in testnet/mainnet

Tags: erc-20, 0x

I am new to the 0x protocol. Is it possible to add custom token using 0x Portal DApp?. Share any example or document.

I have deployed my own exchange medium. it is running in http://localhost:3001

I don't know how to add my custom token in that exchange medium

Answer (score 0):

What is your own Exchange Medium? If you've used [0x Launch Kit](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-launch-kit) then the [FAQ](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-launch-kit/wiki/FAQ#adding-a-custom-token-and-trading-pair) has a walk through on how to add custom tokens.